# I can't write into the Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI interface with buttons for sending daily reports of staff. I got pretty far but I'm completely stuck now, I'm able to create the buttons and everything else, but I can't seem to get it to write into the Tkinter text widget. 
here is the script -

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time;
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("Report system")

text_Input = StringVar()
ADD = "0"


Tops = Frame(root, width = 1600,height = 700, relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width = 650,height = 700, relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=RIGHT)

f2 = Frame(root, width = 950,height = 700, relief=SUNKEN)
f2.pack(side=LEFT)
#======================Time==================================================
localtime=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
#============================Info============================================
TitleH = Label(Tops, font=('arial', 60, 'bold'),text="COMPANY",     fg="blue4",bd=10, anchor='w')
TitleH.configure(background = "powder blue")
TitleH.grid(row=0, column=0)
TitleT = Label(Tops, font=('arial', 60, 'bold'),text=localtime,         fg="blue4",bd=10, anchor='w')
TitleT.configure(background = "powder blue")
TitleT.grid(row=1, column=0)
#==========================Buttondef=======================
def btnClick(PrimeOperator):
    global operator
    operator = str(PrimeOperator)
    text_Input.set(PrimeOperator)

textDisplay = Entry(f2, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=text_Input,         bd=30, insertwidth=4,
                   bg="powder blue", justify='center')
textDisplay.grid(columnspan=4)
#============================text===========================================

statusDisplay = Text(f1, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), bd=60, width = 30,     height = 10,
                   bg="powder blue")
statusDisplay.grid(columnspan=4)

btnadd=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
          text="add", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     statusDisplay.insert(INSERT, 'text_input').grid(row=4,column=2))

#===================OPERATOR=================================
btnop19=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=    ("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="OpTH19", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     btnClick("OpTH19")).grid(row=2,column=0)

btnop18=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="OpTH18", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     
btnClick("OpTH18")).grid(row=2,column=1)

btnop8=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
          text="OpTH08", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     
btnClick("OpTH8")).grid(row=2,column=2)

btnop7=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
          text="OpTH07", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:         
btnClick("OpTH7")).grid(row=3,column=0)

btnop5=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="OpTH05", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     
btnClick("OpTH5")).grid(row=3,column=1)

btnop4=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="OpTH04", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     
btnClick("OpTH4")).grid(row=3,column=2)

btnop3=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="OpTH03", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     btnClick("OpTH3")).grid(row=4,column=1)

#=================================status======================================
btnontime=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=    ("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="On time", bg="powder blue", command=lambda: btnClick("On     Time")).grid(row=2,column=3)
btnlate=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="Is Late", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:     btnClick("Late")).grid(row=3,column=3)
btnonleave=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=    ("arial",20,'bold'),
                  text="On leave", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:         btnClick("On leave")).grid(row=4,column=3)
#=================================Print=======================================
btnadd=Button(f2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=8, fg="black", font=("arial",20,'bold'),
              text="add", bg="powder blue", 
command='C').grid(row=4,column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

So basically I will click on the ontime first then I want to click on the add so it adds ontime to the left side which is a Tkinter text. Then I will click on op who comes on time and clicked add for each one of op. So I want it to look like:

ontime opth3 opth4 etc.. etc..

Comment: What a useless title!

Comment: So the problem is getting the text from an Entry and add it to a Text widget? In other words, 99% of this code isn't relevant to the problem and could/should be removed?

Comment: :(  Biffen do you mean the title of my thread or the title of my code, cuz i change it since it was the company's name, but it it is my thread title then i feel bad for you that you feel it is useless.<3

Comment: Thank you to the people who helped edited my question. Im still new to this and is still learning, only started writing python for a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function for the **add** button to call instead of "C". For example:

```
def addfunction(event=None):
    statusDisplay.insert(END, operator)
```

You will also want some validating code to make sure that global variable **operator** is not undefined or of the wrong type. Also it might be good to keep track of which OPs are already logged so you never log OPs several times.

**Additional explanation:**
The easiest way to make sure that global variable **operator** is not undefined is to set a default value of the correct type before you use it for the first time.

```
operator = ''
```

Otherwise you can check variable type with `if type(operator) == str` for strings. Same syntax for other types. For checking if a variable exists you 
can use a `try` clause.

As for keeping track of inputs, I'm not really sure about exactly what you want. This is also something you'll have to spend some time thinking about. Let me give an example:

Should outputs in `statusDisplay` be separated by spaces, tabs, commas? Is it important if "On time" appears first in a line or doesn't it matter? Is multiline results ok? Do I want "On time" and "Is late" to appear on the same line. Is the results something you will send to another program or function or maybe save to a file; what format will they want?

When you have decided on a behaviour it's much easier to write the code and see if the output is what you want.

Also: try implementing it yourself first, and if it doesn't work you are welcome to ask for further help. Before you do that: read the documentation and google for solutions.

Comment: thank you figbeam that helped me a lot, im still new to it, if you can can you explain to me about the validating code and stuff because i have no idea what they are, but still anyway you pretty solve my problems thank you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me, i will try to write it, and for the statusDisplay i want it to look some thing like this:

Good morning, We have started the morning shift (11am - 7pm). Today workers are 5 people.
Their ID's - op_th_th19, op_th_th14, op_th_th12, op_th_th15, op_th_th24.
Late ID's - 
On leave ID's -

this is the txt that i copy and paste and report to the group chat everyday. i just want to make it so i dont have to keep changing the operator's(staffs) who comes in on each day and also i want it to be more. so yes it will be on separated line.